# How can I export a recursive directory & file listing to a text file in Linux Bash shell with an SSH command?

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, ssh, directory

Assume I'm in my `pwd` - `/home/kparisi/`

What command can I run to export all directories & files from this directory and all subdirectories within it to a text file?

I don't need the contents of the files, just their names & paths (and permissions if possible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on superuser - See e.g. http://superuser.com/a/200684 . You can redirect into a file by appending `> myfile.txt` to the end of the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is a good utility to obtain (recursively) all the content of a directory. If you want the file (and directory) names with their permissions:

```
find /home/kparisi -printf "%M %p\n"
```

You can then use `ssh` to run this command on the remote server:

```
ssh kparisi@remote.com 'find /home/kparisi -printf "%M %p\n"'
```

And finally, if you want to store this in a file on your local server:

```
ssh kparisi@remote.com 'find /home/kparisi -printf "%M %p\n"' > file
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` to get a listing of all the files in a directory and its subdirectories, then pipe it to a file with the `>` operand.

```
find > list.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

I understand that it is an old question, but anyway if somebody will reach this page, maybe will be useful. I love to do this (assume we have the file "fsstruct.txt" to save directory structure):

```
tree > fsstruct.txt
```

for me this format is simpler to read.

It is easy also to use other features of tree:

```
tree -p > fsstruct.txt
```

prints file type and permissions before file and it is more accessible when you are reading plain text, which is a file and which is a directory.

```
tree -h > fsstruct.txt
```

this:`tree -ph > fsstruct.txt` 
prints sizes of files in a human readable format.

Also, it is possible to send output to the file: `tree -ph . -o fsstruct.txt` or create HTML: 
  `tree -Hph . -o tree.html`

Answer (score 2):

The command `find > list.txt` will do. If you want directory tree list `tree -a > list.txt` can be used